# Two-way encryption/authentication between servers and clients

Tags: authentication, encryption

To be honest I don't know if this is the appropriate title since I am completely new to this area, but I will try my best to explain below.

The scenario can be modeled as a group of functionally identical servers and a group of functionally identical clients. Assume each client knows the endpoints of all the servers (possibly from a broker or some kind of name service), and randomly chooses one to talk to.

**Problem 1:** The client and the server first need to authenticate themselves to each other (i.e. the client must show the server that it's a valid client, vice versa).

**Problem 2:** After that, the client and server talk to each other over some kind of encryption.

For Problem 1, I don't know what's the best solution. For Problem 2, I'm thinking about letting each clients create a private key and give the corresponding public key to the server it talks to right after authentication, so that no one else can decrypt its messages; and let all servers share a private key and distribute the corresponding public key to all clients, so that the external world (including the clients) can't decrypt what the clients send to the servers.

These are probably very naive approaches though, so I'd really appreciate any help & thoughts on the problems. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this not directly related to programming. [security.se] is much better suited for this type of question. Please read some posts about similar questions before asking there to reduce the scope of your question, particularly regarding key management constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question about half a year ago here, I've been redirected to [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

After reading through my answer and rethinking your question, if you still have questions that are so broad, I suggest to ask there. StackOverflow, from what I know, is more about programming (thus security in programming) than security concepts. Either way, you will probably have to migrate there at some point when doing your project.

To begin with, you need to seriously consider what needs protecting in your system. Like [here (check Gilles' comment and others)](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89424/designing-a-security-system-for-road-pricing), one of the first and most important things to do is to think over what security measures you have to take. You just mentioned authentication and encryption, but there are many more things that are important, like **data integrity**. Check [wiki page for security measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_security#Key_concepts). After knowing more about these, you can choose what (if any) encryption algorithms, hashing functions and others you need.

For example, forgetting about data integrity is forgetting about hashing, which is the most popular security measure I encounter on SO. By applying encryption, you 'merely' can expect no one else to be able to read the message. But you cannot be sure if it reaches the destination unchanged (if anything), either because of interceptors or signal losses. I assume you need to be sure.

A typical architecture I am aware of, assumes asymmetric encryption for private key exchange and then communicating using private keys. This is because **public-key infrastructure (PKI)** assumes that the key of one of the sides is publicly known, making communication easier, but certainly slower *(e.g. due to key length: RSA [asymmetric] starts with 512bits, but typical key length now is 2048, which I can compare to weakest, but still secure AES [symmetric], which key lengths start with 128bits)*. The problem is, as you stated, the server and user are not authenticated to each other, so the server does not really know if the person sending the data really is who they claim they are. Also, the data could have been changed during traffic.
To prevent that, you need a so called 'key exchange algorithm', such as one of the **Diffie Hellman** schemes (so, **DH** might be the 'raw' answer to both of your problems).

Taking all above into consideration, you might want to use one (or more) of the popular protocols and/or services to define your architecture. Popular ones are **SSH, SSL/TLS and IPSec**. Read about them, define what services you need, check if they are present in one of the services above and you are willing to use the service. If not, you can always design your own using raw crypto algorithms and digests (hashes).